# Issue With Upstart And RVM Gem?

Tags: upstart, ruby, rvm

Im trying to get a RVM gem to run via upstart... I can't seem to get it to work:

siriserver.conf

```
#siriserver
start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn

exec start-stop-daemon --start --exect /root/.siriproxy/siri.sh
```

Then my /siri.sh file is chmod ax and contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -s "home/xbmc/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/home/xbmc/.vrm/scripts/rvm"
siriproxy server -d 192.168.1.100 -u xbmc
```

My upstart log shows the following error:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/siriproxy-.0.5.4/lib/siriproxy 'expand_path': non-absolute home

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I would do a few things:

1. Dump `start-stop-daemon`. Upstart largely replaces it.
2. <del>`su` into the right user from the upstart script (and move the script into /home/xbmc/)</del>
3. Fix the missing `/` in the script.

So I'd end up with something like:

```
start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn

exec /root/.siriproxy/siri.sh
```

And:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ -s "/home/xbmc/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/home/xbmc/.vrm/scripts/rvm"
siriproxy server -d 192.168.1.100 -u xbmc
```

Comment: If i run it is a user, i get this error: 

Please report a bug if this causes problems.
[Info - Configuration] Loading plugins -- If any fail to load, run `siriproxy b$
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
[Error - Server] Either you're not root or tcp/udp port 53 is in use. DNS serve$
[Info - Server] Starting SiriProxy on 0.0.0.0:443...

Comment: If i change the bash file to do rvmsudo siriproxy ... 
the log shows: 
[code]
Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call v$

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=1

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.

In case there is no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=0

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
[code]

Comment: @Don I didn't stop to look what siriproxy does - if it needs to bind to a low port, that's fair enough. I've put a few things back.